# How to fetch data in one select statement in terms of parameter changing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
----------
name | surname
----------
abc  |  def
-----------
xxx  |  def
----------
yyy  |  def
----------
Comy |  Xardas
----------
```

For example, I declare:

```
declare @name varchar(10)

set @name = 'abc'
```

I need to fetch all names whose surnames is equal to `@name's` surname. if `@name` is null then fetch all records. **IN ONE SELECT STATEMENT**

Answer (score 0):

Do a inner join on the same table on column surname

```
SELECT *
FROM   table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.surname = t2.surname 
WHERE  t1.name = COALESCE(@name, t1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
WHERE (ISNULL(@name,0) != 0 AND t1.surname = @name) OR (ISNULL(@name,0)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (name varchar(20), surname varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('abc','def'),('xxx','def'),('yyy','def'), ('Comy','Xardas')

declare @name varchar(10)
set @name = 'abc'

SELECT T.* FROM 
@MyTable T
LEFT JOIN @MyTable T1 ON T.surname = T1.surname AND @name IS NOT NULL
WHERE (T.name = @name or @name IS NULL)
```

Comment: when @name is defined null, all rows becomes null.

Comment: if you set @name= null  then you will get all rows of @MyTable

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
declare @name varchar(10)
set @name = 'abc'
SELECT * 
FROM YT T1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YT T2 WHERE name=@name AND T1.SURNAME=T2.SURNAME) OR @name IS NULL
```

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE YT (name varchar(20), surname varchar(20));
INSERT INTO YT VALUES ('abc','def'),('xxx','def'),('yyy','def'), ('Comy','Xardas');
```

Output wiht name = NULL:

```
name    surname
abc def
xxx def
yyy def
Comy    Xardas
```

Output with name = 'abc':

```
name    surname
abc def
xxx def
yyy def
```